# Android data storage, When to use SqlLite and when to use JSON, Linq alternatives

Tags: android, json, performance, sqlite

I have a few years of exp with webdev using .Net and C#... and one feature I really enjoy there is the linq-expressions for quering for data.. is there anything that simulair for Android using to query against JSONs or against the SqlLite database? (I guess im looking for a typed expression/query-framework).

And for my next question.. Which one of the JSON approach and the SQLLite approach am I supposed to use.. and when? I know this has been asked a million times.. but there doesnt seem to be any strict answers..

Is SQLLite for more complex querying and when Im having a bigger ammount of data, while JSON is used while having a smaller ammount of data and not very much querying is needed?

Could I store all my JSON data in the memmory for faster read/write access?..since I have heard that storing it in the storage/on disk might be a slow process.

But on the other hand I also have heard that SQLLite is slow in generall...

And finally.. when we are speaking of "slow" is it slow like, a single read/write looks up the entire application for a few milisecs or is it slow like compared to a in-memory-database that executes queries and stuff fast as lightning

Answer (score 9):

> When to use SQLite

`SQLite` is one form of how to persist your data, how to secure your data. Generally if you want to store larger quantum of data and have quick access to them(and also if these data are "sensitive"), `SQLite` is great choice. Hence i disagree with your opition that `SQLite` is slow, definitely not i guess.

I have `SQLite` database with approximately with 650 000 records and still smart performance(an usage of indexes is sometimes necessary).

> When to use JSON

`JSON` is lightweight data structure designed for human-readable data interchange and what is main is language-independent. It's very good choice(maybe the best) if you want send data via network(send data to remote server etc.) but i think not very good for data persisting also it's not safe as SQLite is.

Generally you should compare `JSON` with `XML` but you can't compare SQLite and JSON which are two different things.

Answer (score 3):

General Idea

SqlLite : [For Local Storage](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

JSON : [For Server SideStore](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to compare SQLite and JSON. One is a storage solution, the other one is a data format.

You should probably read the official guide before deciding which storage solution to choose (SQLite, preferences, file system,...): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

If you want to go for SQLite persistence you can use some third-party ORM to make queries easier (e.g [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) is the most popular one)

Comment: yes Im aware of that JSON is a format :).. so what Im actually meaning is stroing json-formatted text in a file for later read and write operations against that file, compared to using SQLLite :).

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't understand that your question was about SQLite VS File storage. The link I mentioned should help you anyway.